# Too few arguments to sqlite3_open in XCode

Tags: macos, sqlite

This line of code

```
if (sqlite3_open(([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

generates an error saying that there are too few arguments to sqlite3_open. How many arguments are required? How can this be fixed?

Comment: awakeFromNib: Please tag your questions more accurately. See my edits to your last two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your brackets in not quite the right place - so you're calling sqlite3_open( ) with just *one* argument, the result of the 'is-equal' test.

This is probably closer:

```
if ( sqlite3_open( [databasePath UTF8String], &database ) == SQLITE_OK )
```

See also the [docs for sqlite3_open( )](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open) - there are three alternative signatures, accepting 2 or 4 args:

```
int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
int sqlite3_open16(
  const void *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-16) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
int sqlite3_open_v2(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb,         /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
  int flags,              /* Flags */
  const char *zVfs        /* Name of VFS module to use */
);
```